# How to create multi users account?

Tags: command-line

I want to create multi users with generate password and print out as text file, how can I write in shell script? (Ex: Create 5 users, password 10 length)

Answer (score 0):

The following script does what you asked:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl   

my $user="user";
my $encrypted;
my $userno=1;
my $userstogenerate=6;

sub encryptingPsw {
  my $psw = shift;
  my $count = shift; 
  my @salt = ('.', '/', 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9');  
  my $salt = "";
  $salt.= $salt[rand(63)] foreach(1..$count);
  crypt($psw, $salt);
}

for ($userno;$userno<$userstogenerate;$userno++) {
    print "User name $userno: ";
    chomp (my $user = <STDIN>);
    $encrypted = &encryptingPsw('passwd', 4); 
    print "sudo useradd -p '$encrypted'  $user\n";
    @array = `echo "Username: " $user "Password: " $encrypted >> users.txt`;
}
@array = `cat users.txt | lpr`;
```

New users and their passwords are written in `users.txt` file. If you have attached at the machine a printer, the file will `users.txt` be printed. If not, an error will appear in this sense.